# how to move one page to another without base page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could you please tell me how to move move one page to another in angular without base.html ..
Here is my plunker .
http://plnkr.co/edit/NBNOPS76DvUI1AfPxxnA?p=preview

In other words I will explain I make a base.html file in that I load my first page having bottom "Test Come" .There is a button in my first view on click I go to second view "second.html" My problem is that I don't want to show "Test Come" on second view So I remove   **parent:'b',**.It not show anything .
Could you please tell me how To achieve that here is my controller

```
var loginCntrl=function($scope,$location,$state){
  $scope.testClick =function(){
    alert('sss');
     $state.go("appaa");


  }

$scope.name="naveen";
$scope.lastname="sharam";
$scope.fullname = function() {
    return $scope.firstname + $scope.lastname;
};
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting this http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzlFIJadnZ1M7fpzNNSa?p=preview ...

Comment: yes ..I am expecting the same .May I used parent propery everytime ?

Comment: In your case, Instead of maintaining as single view, you can named multiple view in index.html. http://plnkr.co/edit/cSiRpRMtNHWmWGwzYMK2?p=preview .. By this way, you can avoid parent concept for navigation type 2 ..